# Spring Webflux - Server/Client threads utilisation

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I'm playing with Spring Webflux (2.0.3.RELEASE) with Netty and try to understand how threads are utilised by server and web client. I wrote some piece of code with chain of http calls with WebClient. I suspected that all calls are non-blocking but I can't figure out why only one request went through entire chain. This is the code and log output below:

```
public class DemoApplication {

private WebClient webclient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new DemoApplication().startServer();
}

public void startServer() throws Exception {
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = routingFunction();
    HttpHandler httpHandler = RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(route);
    ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    server.newHandler(adapter).block();
    Thread.sleep(1000000);
}

public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routingFunction() throws Exception {
    return route(path("/1"), req -> ok().body(fromPublisher(get1(), String.class)))
            .andRoute(path("/2"), req -> ok().body(fromPublisher(get2(), String.class)))
            .andRoute(path("/3"), req -> ok().body(fromPublisher(get3(), String.class)));
}

public Mono<String> get1() {
    System.out.println("---------REQUEST---------");
    System.out.println("1: " + Thread.currentThread());
    return webclient.get().uri("2").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
}

public Mono<String> get2() {
    System.out.println("2: " + Thread.currentThread());
    return webclient.get().uri("3").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
}

public Mono<String> get3() {
    System.out.println("3: " + Thread.currentThread());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1250000); // simulate thread somehow got blocked
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    return Mono.just("test");
}
}
```

I made a 4 calls to localhost:8080/1 and get following output. Only one request managed to reach third method. I expected that when one thread got blocked then other three will be able to handle other requests but they didn't. Whole thread pool consisted of 4 threads (same as number of cores).

```
---------REQUEST---------
1: Thread[reactor-http-nio-2,5,main]
2: Thread[reactor-http-nio-4,5,main]
3: Thread[reactor-http-nio-2,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
1: Thread[reactor-http-nio-3,5,main]
2: Thread[reactor-http-nio-1,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
1: Thread[reactor-http-nio-3,5,main]
2: Thread[reactor-http-nio-1,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
1: Thread[reactor-http-nio-3,5,main]
2: Thread[reactor-http-nio-1,5,main]
```

Could you please explain that behaviour?

**--------EDIT-------**

Explanation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netty/1kAS-FJWGRE

Answer (score 2):

You already know that, but other developers reading this: you should never use blocking operations in a Reactor application - or if you do, you should schedule that work on an elastic `Scheduler` and be aware of the tradeoffs.

If you ever want to simulate a remote service taking a long time to respond, you can use `delay*` operators for that without artificially blocking a Thread. In this case, I guess you'd like to simulate the fact that part of your app is using blocking I/O in a reactive pipeline.

I think the behavior you're seeing here has something to do with the fact that the server is calling itself and that both `WebClient` and the Netty server are sharing the same `EventLoopGroup`. I don't know about the implementation details of work stealing in that case.

I've simplified this example with a blocking handler like this:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routingFunction() throws Exception {
    return route(all(), this::handler);
}

Mono<ServerResponse> handler(ServerRequest request) {
    System.out.println("---------REQUEST---------");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1250000); // simulate thread somehow got blocked
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    return ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

In this case, calling that server with a `curl` client shows the following behavior, as expected (on a 8 cores laptop).

```
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-2,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-3,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-4,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-5,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-6,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-7,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-8,5,main]
---------REQUEST---------
Thread[reactor-http-nio-1,5,main]
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I digged a little bit and found out that this is not because of self calling but how channels are assigned to workers
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netty/1kAS-FJWGRE